# How to comment out python code using sed command

Tags: python, sed, comments

I want to comment out following line of code using the **sed** command.

Actual Code:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.zip' % file_name.replace('.shp','')
response['Content-length'] = str(len(zip_stream))
response['Content-Type'] = mimetype
response.write(zip_stream)
return response
```

What I wanted:

```
#response = HttpResponse()
#response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.zip' % file_name.replace('.shp','')
#response['Content-length'] = str(len(zip_stream))
#response['Content-Type'] = mimetype
#response.write(zip_stream)
#return response
```

Only problem is file is huge and it contains `response` everywhere, so searching should be more specific in accordance to provide provide above.

The given code block lies in middle of the entire source code of particular file.

Comment: So you want to comment out any line that contains the variable name `response`? Your question isn't that clear.

Comment: Sorry for confusion..
No, I simply wants to comment out provided specific block, as code contains response at various places we can use response to match it.
from entire source code, i do want to comment out above mentioned block only..

Comment: Why not just comment that out by hand then? Otherwise there is no pattern (to speak of) for sed to work with.

Comment: so your problem is not batch replace or something. it's more like how to find the block you want. instead of searching "response", have you tried search an entire line of code? e.g. "response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.zip' % file_name.replace('.shp','')"?

Comment: I am working on `Shell Script` which will be an auto installer for one fairly _complicated_ to install, an open source project.
At present there isn't any easy option available for users, those who wants try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a few assumptions about what you are trying to do here. I'm assuming you want to comment a code block between two lines of your choice. Here's one way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -i '/response = HttpResponse()/,/return response/s/.*/#&/' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked quite well.. on test file now i will try it on my actual code.. :)

Comment: @ steve - Yes, it worked very well on actual code as well.. :) Thank you once again..

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i -ne 'if(/response = Http/../return response/){$_="#".$_}print' your_file
```